# Adding a filter to query for row# in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, row, xlookup

```
ROWS(B1:XLOOKUP(P22,B:B,B:B)
```

The above snippet returns the first row# where a value in column B matches P22. How would I add a filter to only return row#'s where J:J="foo"?

```
filter(ROWS(B1:XLOOKUP(P22,B:B,B:B),J:J="foo")
```

This doesn't work.

Update:

```
=XLOOKUP(P22&J22,ARRAYFORMULA(B:B&J:J),B:B)
```

J22="foo"

This returns the data from the first row in column B where a value matches P22, and the value in column J matches "foo". So we have succeeded in returning the correct row, now I just need it to return the actual row# instead of "foo".

```
=XLOOKUP(P22&J22,ARRAYFORMULA(B:B&J:J),return row # here)
```

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: "In the example above, if we searched for “Jennifer”, we would only be able to see the related values for the first match, “Jennifer Smith”. To be able to narrow down our results to the correct match, it can be helpful to combine multiple criteria. The best way to do this in XLOOKUP formulas is use a simple Array Formula like this:"

Comment: https://coefficient.io/google-sheet-xlookup#:~:text=XLOOKUP%20with%20FILTER%20function&text=The%20FILTER%20function%20is%20one,the%20basic%20FILTER%20function%20syntax.&text=Specify%20the%20range%20containing%20the,(F3)%20to%20your%20formula

Comment: I think it's an array that is needed.

Comment: ok I have updated my question because I have managed to return data from the correct row, now I just need to return the actual row#. I will share a spread sheet example later today if needed.

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with input and your desired output so I can correctly understand your concern.